# Interstitials ads are not displayed

Tags: android, admob

I added the `admob Interstitials` ads in the application but ads are not displaying in the app. Instead of this Google shows on this page. Please help me to add the `Interstitials` ads instead of this.

How can I place the `Interstitials` ads in the application.

Thanks in advance.

Check this image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWs4e.png

Comment: I assume you are using house ads? Cause only a small, invited group of developers can add payed interstitials ads. For everyone else it's only for house ads.

Comment: @RaymondP But What to configure this for receiving the full screen size ads.

Comment: @RaymondP If i add the House ads then will i charge for this. please hint me for this